# How to get directory folder property in Win32 API?

Tags: winapi, properties, size, directory

I want to get directory folder property such as: Date Created, Size, Folder Name,... in WIN32 API using C/C++. What can I do?
Thanks for helping,

Answer (score 1):

Use the [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.
You can also use the [_stat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) function.

Comment: FindFirst file des exactly what you want. It fills the WIN32_FIND_DATA structure with the information you require. You will find the creation time in the ftCreationTime field, the last write time in ftLastWriteTime and do on. Where is the problem ??

Answer (score 0):

```
    WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA fileAttr;
    if (!GetFileAttributesEx(dirPath.c_str(), GetFileExInfoStandard, &fileAttr))
        return false;
    SYSTEMTIME st;
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&fileAttr.ftCreationTime, &st);
```

use [GetFileAttributesEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364946.aspx).